# StatsModels SARIMAX with exogenous variable and linear time trend

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

I am trying to forecast a SARIMAX model with a the linear time trend taking the value 1 for the first datapoint in the and and increasing by 1 for each successive observation up to N= sample size. The trend term is introduced because of it improves the model’s predictive power significantly but we want to freeze it out  to the last observed value for out-sample forecasting. Namely if in-sample size is 100 we want to use this value for each step in the forecasting insted of increasing by 1 at each step

The model has been fitted as follows

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

model = SARIMAX(endog=Unemployment_series,exog=sm.add_constant(insample['GDP_yoy'].values),order=(1,0,0),trend ='t').fit(disp=-1)
```

According  to statsmodels documentation in https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html, the parameter trend allows us to fix the linear time trend.

The problem arises when try to forecast using the methods get_forecast or get_prediction

```py
forecast = model.get_forecast(steps=len(outsample),exog = sm.add_constant(outsample['GDP_yoy'].values,has_constant='add'))
```

or

```py
forecast = model.get_prediction(start=len(insample),end=len(insample)+len(outsample)-1,exog = sm.add_constant(outsample['GDP_yoy'].values,has_constant='add'))
```

Because of I have not found any parameter that allows to control  the behavior of the time trend, any advice?